# How do I restrict end users to access my AWS elastic-search domain endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am using AWS elastic-search domain for searching on various records in my web app as well as android app, but when I search from server side using c# NEST it's take too much time, so that now I am using JavaScript that can directly point to elastic-search and can search within a time, problem is when I use to connect elastic-search domain the endpoint is visible and anyone can steal my data with that, so how can I fix this issue ether from AWS or any other solution?

I have gave some access policy where any other user can only make get and post request, but it's doesn't work to protect my data

Comment: have you tried using IAM to authenticate your aws elasticsearch domain? you can attach the policy to a cognito user OR you can give the token yourself (without cognito) by using a custom API which you can write.

Comment: No, how do i do it that? @kkesley

Comment: I don't know what's your experience regarding IAM permissions / cognito. I can give you a link but just let me know if you need help in certain area. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-control-access-to-your-amazon-elasticsearch-service-domain/

Comment: Hi @kkesley I have just read blog which you have sent. But if I give IAM permissions to my elastic-search domain access policy then how do I connect using JavaScript? or am I doing or getting something wrong?

Comment: you have to make a signed http request. The easiest way probably is to create a lambda and sign the request there. Then, give the request signature to your js app. You can check how to sign a http request here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-node

Comment: the lambda should have the role which is allowed to access the elasticsearch domain